# Android camera encoding through OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I was taking a look at the BigFlake examples of video encoding, namely this one:

http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt

And I was wondering if this method is fundamentally faster than just using onPreviewFrame method from the CameraCallback object itself to retrieve the raw bytes of the image and feed them to the encoder.

If this is the case, then can anyone explain to me the reason why this is faster?

Comment: Was curious myself, but I don't see onCameraPreview in the Android docs. What are you referring to?

Comment: its called `onPreviewFrame` actually https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both yes and no, depending on what you do.

If you get the raw bytes from the camera preview callback, the pixel data needs to be passed from the media server process into your app's process, and from your app back into the media server process into the encoder. The pixel data is kept in YUV format all the way, but your app might need to convert it from one YUV layout to another (encoders can accept pixel data in a few different formats, which aren't necessarily one of the same as what the camera provides in the public API).

If you pass the frames from the camera to the encoder via EGL/OpenGL, the actual pixel data never needs to pass into your process, but is kept in opaque surfaces, where all the format conversions are handled by the graphics hardware. This does on one hand involve converting the pixel data from YUV from the camera into RGB when passing through OpenGL, back into YUV when going to the encoder, but all of this is abstracted away.

So depending on the quality and amount of optimizations spent on the camera drivers and EGL/OpenGL drivers, that approach can probably be as fast or faster. Especially if you want to do some sort of processing on the image data, if it can be done in a GL shader. The camera preview callback approach might seem more straightforward, but it actually has quite a bit of inherent overhead in passing the data into your app's process.

Comment: I see so its just actually passing the bytes on that causes the overhead? Also I think the encoding process is happening on the native (as in C code) level since sometimes an SIGENV /libc error is thrown when encoding. Maybe keeping it all "native" also contributes to this speeding?

Comment: Passing the bytes from one process to another is one part of it yes, and passing the bytes into a java byte array is another. (With the newer Camera2 API, you can get the frames in direct byte buffers which should potentially have a little less overhead). And then when passing the data back to the encoder, you do the same in reverse. But additionally, when the pixel data is exposed to you, it has to be converted to one of the public standard pixel layouts in the camera API, while as long as it is hidden as in the OpenGL case, it can stay in whatever format the hardware prefers.

Comment: with "pixel layouts" you mean the color format like NV21, NV19, etc.?

Comment: Yes. The camera API returns the pixel data in NV21 (or YV12 if requested), while the encoders normally accept NV12 or I420 (which also is what I would suspect that the camera internall originally delivers). On the other hand, converting between those formats doesn't cost much extra once one already is copying the data.